# Debugging a slow thumbnailer process

Tags: fonts, strace, gdb, svg

I am trying a debug a peculiar performance behavior
in the thumbnail-generating process for [`eog`](https://wiki.gnome.org/Apps/EyeOfGnome),
specifically [`gdk-pixbuf`](https://developer.gnome.org/gdk-pixbuf/).
The minimal files to reproduce are here:

https://github.com/nbeaver/gdk-pixbuf-bug

The process tree looks like this:

```
systemd,1 splash
  `-plasmashell,4366
      `-konsole,6783
          `-bash,6793
              `-make,6949 reproduce
                  `-eog,6973 /usr/share/doc/docutils-doc/docs/user/images
                      `-bwrap,10071 --ro-bind /usr /usr --ro-bind /bin /bin --ro-bind /lib64 /lib64 --ro-bind /lib /lib --ro-bind /sbin /sbin --proc /proc --dev /dev --chdir / --setenv GIO_USE_VFS local --unshare-all --die-with-parent --bind /tmp/gnome-desktop-thumbnailer-2HUN5Z /tmp --ro-bind /usr/share/doc/docutils-doc/docs/user/images/s5-files.svg /tmp/gnome-desktop-file-to-thumbnail.svg --seccomp 11 /usr/bin/gdk-pixbuf-thumbnailer -s 128 file:///tmp/gnome-desktop-file-to-thumbnail.svg /tmp/gnome-desktop-thumbnailer.png
                          `-bwrap,10074 --ro-bind /usr /usr --ro-bind /bin /bin --ro-bind /lib64 /lib64 --ro-bind /lib /lib --ro-bind /sbin /sbin --proc /proc --dev /dev --chdir / --setenv GIO_USE_VFS local --unshare-all --die-with-parent --bind /tmp/gnome-desktop-thumbnailer-2HUN5Z /tmp --ro-bind /usr/share/doc/docutils-doc/docs/user/images/s5-files.svg /tmp/gnome-desktop-file-to-thumbnail.svg --seccomp 11 /usr/bin/gdk-pixbuf-thumbnailer -s 128 file:///tmp/gnome-desktop-file-to-thumbnail.svg /tmp/gnome-desktop-thumbnailer.png
                              `-gdk-pixbuf-thum,10075 -s 128 file:///tmp/gnome-desktop-file-to-thumbnail.svg /tmp/gnome-desktop-thumbnailer.png
```

From the [`strace` log](https://github.com/nbeaver/gdk-pixbuf-bug/blob/master/strace_1564026245.log),
it looks like `/usr/bin/gdk-pixbuf-thumbnailer` is spending about 30 seconds
looking at font files:

```
22:44:05 munmap(0x7fd491988000, 20930832) = 0 <0.000558>
22:44:05 openat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/share/fonts/opentype/noto/NotoSansCJK-Bold.ttc", O_RDONLY) = 5 <0.000060>
22:44:05 fcntl(5, F_SETFD, FD_CLOEXEC)  = 0 <0.000014>
22:44:05 fstat(5, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=20930832, ...}) = 0 <0.000013>
22:44:05 mmap(NULL, 20930832, PROT_READ, MAP_PRIVATE, 5, 0) = 0x7fd491988000 <0.000021>
22:44:05 close(5)                       = 0 <0.000011>
22:44:06 munmap(0x7fd491988000, 20930832) = 0 <0.000525>
22:44:06 openat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/share/fonts/opentype/noto/NotoSansCJK-Bold.ttc", O_RDONLY) = 5 <0.000076>
22:44:06 fcntl(5, F_SETFD, FD_CLOEXEC)  = 0 <0.000013>
22:44:06 fstat(5, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=20930832, ...}) = 0 <0.000012>
22:44:06 mmap(NULL, 20930832, PROT_READ, MAP_PRIVATE, 5, 0) = 0x7fd491988000 <0.000023>
22:44:06 close(5)                       = 0 <0.000013>
<snip>
22:44:31 stat("/usr/share/fonts/opentype/stix-word/STIXMath-Regular.otf", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=476872, ...}) = 0 <0.000024>
22:44:31 openat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/share/fonts/opentype/stix-word/STIXMath-Regular.otf", O_RDONLY) = 5 <0.000026>
22:44:31 fcntl(5, F_SETFD, FD_CLOEXEC)  = 0 <0.000014>
22:44:31 fstat(5, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=476872, ...}) = 0 <0.000013>
22:44:31 mmap(NULL, 476872, PROT_READ, MAP_PRIVATE, 5, 0) = 0x7fd49c26a000 <0.000023>
22:44:31 close(5)                       = 0 <0.000015>
```

There is a particular SVG that triggers this behavior.
However, it's not enough to just run `eog`
or `gdk-pixbuf-thumbnailer` on the SVG.
This behavior only happens when:

- running `eog` on a directory;
- there is a particular SVG in the directory
  that does not already have a thumbnail in `~/.cache/thumbnails/`.

  (I use `touch` to update the timestamp of the SVG
  and make the thumbnailer run again every time.)
- there is at least one other image in the same directory;
- and the other image has a filename that collates *before* the SVG filename.

  (If the filename collates *after* the SVG filename,
  it generates the thumbnail in less than a second.
  Otherwise it takes around 30 seconds.)

There are some other puzzles, too.
In the [`strace` log](https://github.com/nbeaver/gdk-pixbuf-bug/blob/master/strace_1564026245.log),
the wall clock times don't seem to match the time spent in the system calls.
I've run `eog` under `strace` with the `-f` flag:

> `-f`
>
> Trace child processes as they are created  by  currently  traced processes as
>   a result of the fork(2), vfork(2) and clone(2) system calls.

and I've also tried the `-ff` flag:

> `-ff`
>
> If the `-o filename` option is in effect, each processes trace  is written
>   to  `filename.pid` where `pid` is the numeric process id of each process.

but in either case
`gdk-pixbuf-thumbnailer` doesn't show up in the logfiles of child processes.

I'm also having trouble running `gdb` on `gdk-pixbuf-thumbnailer`
(something about "Target and debugger are in different PID namespaces"),
so I can't tell where it's getting stuck.

```
$ sudo gdb -p 20789
[sudo] password for nathaniel:
<snip>
Error while mapping shared library sections:
Could not open `target:/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libbsd.so.0' as an executable file: No such file or directory

warning: Unable to find dynamic linker breakpoint function.
GDB will be unable to debug shared library initializers
and track explicitly loaded dynamic code.

warning: Target and debugger are in different PID namespaces; thread lists and other data are likely unreliable.  Connect to gdbserver inside the container.
(gdb) quit
Detaching from program: target:/newroot/usr/bin/gdk-pixbuf-thumbnailer, process 20789
```

I'm guessing this has to do with the `bwrap` container.

Version information:

```
$ apt-cache policy libgdk-pixbuf2.0-bin eog
libgdk-pixbuf2.0-bin:
  Installed: 2.36.11-2
  Candidate: 2.36.11-2
  Version table:
 *** 2.36.11-2 500
        500 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
eog:
  Installed: 3.28.1-1
  Candidate: 3.28.1-1
  Version table:
 *** 3.28.1-1 500
        500 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
```

My questions are:

- Is this bug reproducible on other machines and other versions?

  (I happen to be using Ubuntu 18.04,
  but I want to know if this happens on other distributions.)
- Why isn't `strace -f` picking up `/usr/bin/gdk-pixbuf-thumbnailer`
  as a child process of `eog`?

  Does `eog` use an unusual method to create child processes?
- How can I use `gdb` to attach to the
  `/usr/bin/gdk-pixbuf-thumbnailer` process
  and see what function it's spending time in?
- What might be causing this behavior?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After hitting upon the right combination of web search keywords,
I am 90% sure this is a duplicate of this bug from December 15, 2018:

> **Slow thumbnail generation due to font issues**
>
> So I was investigating a slowdown in eog while auto-reloading SVG files, and
>   it seems the problem was in the thumbnail generation, which was taking ~10s.
>   (For a tiny SVG, mind you.) More specifically, `gdk-pixbuf-thumbnailer`
>   complained about not finding a font config and spent a lot of time looking at
>   fonts. Adding `--ro-bind /var/cache/fontconfig /var/cache/fontconfig` to the
>   arguments for bwrap fixed the issue and the time is down to ~0.2s.

https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/gnome-desktop/issues/90

It's mentioned here:

> ...and we have also the huge slowdown, see
>   https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/gnome-desktop/issues/90

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-desktop3/+bug/1795668

The fix is a patch in `gnome-desktop3`.

> **thumbnail: Fix slow thumbnailer due to missing font cache**
>
> On some distributions, the font cache doesn't live in /usr but in /var, which
>   we don't allow access to when sandboxing the thumbnailers. Bind mount the
>   fontconfig cache directory read-only if it lives outside /usr, to speed up
>   thumbnailer startup.

https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/gnome-desktop/merge_requests/25/diffs

It looks like the fix is in gnome-desktop3 version 3.30 and later,
so as of July 19, 2019, that is only
Ubuntu 19.10 (Eoan Ermine, unreleased) and
19.04 (Disco Dingo, end of life January 2020).

https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-desktop3

https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-desktop3/+publishinghistory

Version information for my machine:

```
$ apt-cache policy libgnome-desktop-3-17
libgnome-desktop-3-17:
  Installed: 3.28.2-0ubuntu1.5
  Candidate: 3.28.2-0ubuntu1.5
  Version table:
 *** 3.28.2-0ubuntu1.5 500
        500 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     3.28.2-0ubuntu1.3 500
        500 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security/main amd64 Packages
     3.28.1-1ubuntu1 500
        500 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/main amd64 Packages
```